# Laravel redirect to route with parameter issue

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am redirecting from this url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/aalc/submit_paper_step_one/9

to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/aalc/submit_paper_step_one/9

in order to do that i am trying laravel default method of route redirecting

this is my route code

```
Route::get('/submit_paper_step_two/{paper_url_id}','HomeController@submit_paper_step_two')->name('submit_paper_step_two')->middleware('guard.verified:'.$journal->journal_slug.','.$journal->journal_slug.'.verification.notice');
```

and this is how i am redirecting

```
return redirect()->route( $this->current_guard.'.submit_paper_step_two', [ 'paper_url_id' => $id ] );
```

and i am being redirected to this url which is wrong

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/aalc/submit_paper_step_two?paper_url_id=9
```

am i doing any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days if figured it out by myself that 
my route scenario was like this

```
Route::get('/submit_paper_step_two/{paper_url_id}','HomeController@submit_paper_step_two')->name('submit_paper_step_two')->middleware('guard.verified:'.$journal->journal_slug.','.$journal->journal_slug.'.verification.notice');

Route::post('/submit_paper_step_two','HomeController@submit_paper_step_two')->name('submit_paper_step_two')->middleware('guard.verified:'.$journal->journal_slug.','.$journal->journal_slug.'.verification.notice');
```

i defined two routes with same name but different methods so in order to achieve my goal
i changed the second route name and it worked

```
Route::get('/submit_paper_step_two/{paper_url_id}','HomeController@submit_paper_step_two')->name('submit_paper_step_two')->middleware('guard.verified:'.$journal->journal_slug.','.$journal->journal_slug.'.verification.notice');

Route::post('/submit_paper_step_two','HomeController@submit_paper_step_two')->name('submit_paper_step_two_post')->middleware('guard.verified:'.$journal->journal_slug.','.$journal->journal_slug.'.verification.notice');
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Change this your route code

```
Route::get('/submit_paper_step_one/{id}','HomeController@submit_paper_step_two')->name('submit_paper_step_one');
```

Step 2: use this redirecting in your code

```
return redirect()->route('submit_paper_step_one', $id );
```